# Are there midnight commander plugins?

Tags: mc, plugin

I've had an idea for a while regarding an ncurses-based SVN repository browser, and I'm beginning to think that a little handywork on MC could yield promising results.

Does anyone know if MC (midnight commander) have plugins or extensions? Something similar would be how emacs and vim have plugins that can extend their functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge there are not any plugins or extensions to MC, I looked through the features list and did not see anything either (https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc). Though it has been discussed here:

https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/3004